# Using macbook running Lion, some software I'm using thinks there's an external monitor

Tags: display

I'm using the plotting package Veusz and when I last used it I had my mac plugged into an external monitor using VGA, with Veusz on the external. I just have my mac at the moment, and Veusz is still opening on a second desktop, even though there's not one. I have tried 'Detect displays' and this doesn't help, since my mac appears to know that there is not a second monitor. How can I move the window back to my desktop without having to plug it in to another monitor and drag it across?

Comment: Hate asking this, but, did you try rebooting? Most of these *multiple-displays* issues are solved after a reboot.

Comment: I did, and no joy

Comment: How do you know that the package still opens the windows on the second desktop? Can you exclude that it is not a different, unrelated bug?

Comment: When I swipe to Mission Control the window for it pans across from the right hand side. It's done this before, I've just always had an external monitor around, I normally make a point to drag the window for it back to my mac's screen before closing the program or disconnecting the external monitor. I thought now would be a good time to try and find a way to fix it with just my mac, seeing as that's all I've got to hand at the moment.

Comment: Seems like a bug in Veusz -- it's not gracefully handling the case where the secondary display no longer exists. Does the app have a "Window" menu? If so, maybe the "Zoom" option will bring the window back. Either way, you might contact the author(s) about the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I use a window manager by default (I highly recommend them anyway) and that will let you move windows back (my personal recomendation is Divy http://mizage.com/divvy/ - but I think they are all pretty similar)